# Divisibility if a is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose that $a |(4 b+5 c)$ and $a |(2 b+2 c) .$ Prove that if $a$ is odd, then $a | b$ and $a | c$

So since  $a |(2 b+2 c)$ this imply  $a |(4 b+4 c)$ so    $a |(4 b+5 c)$  after subtraction of two dividend we directly get  $a | c$ but I am unable to get why it should divide $b$ if $a$ is odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a$ must divide $4b+5c-2(2b+2c)=c$

$a$ must divide $2b+2c-2(c)=2b$

Now if $a$ is odd $a\nmid2,a$ must divide the odd part of $b$

Comment: Do you mean "The odd part of $2b$"?

Comment: @Arthur, Actually of $b$ or of $2b$

Comment: Well, it is the $2$ in $2b$ we want to get rid of, not the even part of $b$. So I would think that "the odd part of $2b$" would be the most suitable term.